# Want to move text in photo more into the center

Tags: html, reactjs

Here is the code that is from the image. The image only shows the text from the beginning code but want to know how to move the text more into the center of the page. Using React.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u87g.png)

```
                        <div className="text-black-50 text-center opacity-100 pt-3 m-5 p-5">
                            
                            <div className="d-flex align-items-center ml-5">
                                <div className="display-4 text-black-70">
                                    <strong>Scope</strong>                                
                                </div>
                            </div>                            
                            
                            <div className="display-12 text-black-50 text-left opacity-90 pt-3 ml-5 mr-5 mb-5">
                                This Cookie Policy (“Policy”) explains how New Relic, Inc. and its subsidiaries (“New Relic”), use cookies and other similar technologies on our: (1) websites, such as: http://www.newrelic.com, https://www.newrelic.de, discuss.newrelic.com, learn.newrelic.com, docs.newrelic.com, and any related New Relic website  (together the “Site”); and (2) the New Relic product services that you purchase, such as: rpm.newrelic.com, synthetics.newrelic.com, insights.newrelic.com, infrastructure.newrelic.com, and any other services sold by New Relic (together the “Services”). This policy does not apply to cookies that may be part of New Relic’s product offerings placed on our customers’ websites, for which our customers are the data controller. For more information on those cookies, please see the applicable documentation. This policy does not apply to the privacy practices of third party websites which may be linked to this Site.  This Policy was last updated on June 21, 2018.
                            </div>

                            <div className="d-flex align-items-center ml-5">
                                <div className="display-4 text-black-70">
                                    <strong>Consent</strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="display-12 text-black-50 text-left opacity-90 pt-3 ml-5 mr-5 mb-5">
                                By continuing to visit our Site or use our Services, you are agreeing to the use of cookies and other similar technologies for the purposes we describe in this Policy.
                            </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean all the text in the image, including titles ?

Comment: Yes all the text including titles

Comment: can you provide a codesandbox or some of the CSS or something that we can use to see what your current setup is? `display-4` for instance isn't really clear what it is doing. My guess is that class is making the text align to the left